# CSS: are images requested if stated in CSS but later over-ridden?

Tags: css, background-image

I'm building a web site that uses a fair amount of drop shadows and gradients. I can accomplish a lot of this via CSS's box-shadow properties.

Alas, we're still supporting IE, so we need to add background images in those situations.

I could be lazy and just give everyone the background images, but I'm trying to streamline things for those that are using the modern browsers. Ideally, I'd like to have those users not have to request the images.

So, I'm adding an extra class via javascript if the browser supports the box shadow (box-shadowSupport) and my CSS ends up looking like this:

```
.box {
    background: url('myImage.jpg');
}

.box-shadowSupport {
    background: none;
    [box shadow properties go here] 
}
```

If the HTML ends up looking like this:

```
<div class="box box-shadowSupport"></div>
```

Will the image be requested? Or does the browser understand that it isn't needed due to the second style over-riding the background image property?

If the image is requested, I need to rearrange my CSS and javascript so instead of over-riding a style via the cascade, I'll have to swap out the classes so the first isn't even referenced in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

I believe every web browser will treat this in it's own way - as usual :) My suggestion is to use a web proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and see, if the image has been requested or not. And of course, test this in the different browsers.

Answer (score 2):

What you might want to consider is defining the IE specific styles in a separate sheet and loading it with [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx), like this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="ie-css" href="ie-specific.css"
    type="text/css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
```

This will only load the sheet with IE-specific settings and you can override the other classes with `!important` markers.  Conditional comments have been around since IE5, and any other browser will ignore the block above.

Comment: The catch (at least in this case) is that there isn't a clear division between IE browsers and the rest. In some cases I'm looking for FF and WebKit browsers. Sometimes I'm adding Opera to the list. Etc.

Comment: Probably the best bet is to use something like Fiddler to trace the HTTP requests then.  I suspect every browser will be different.  Check out fiddler here: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend just to skip the shadows in IE.

Most people use only one browser and they won't know that there have to be shadows. It isn't a big deal if the site looks different in different browsers as long they look normal (that means not glitchy).

Otherwise use with a if tag for ie specific css, and you can do drop-shadow there with:

```
.box {
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(
            color=#818181,
            offX=5, offY=5, 
            positive=true);
}
```

For more about that [see here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css3_box_shadows_box_shadow_property/).

Comment: That would be my preference as well. Alas, it's not my decision. ;o) I wasn't aware of the IE filter for drop shadow. Good info.

Comment: Ah...alas, it appears the filter option creates a solid (not blurred) and opaque shadow. Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that all modern browsers **will** load 'myImage.jpg'. Actually, the code you provided described the pure CSS way of preloading images without using javascript :)

Comment: I'm thinking it's better to err on the side of assuming that it is going to load the image. As such, I think I'm going to create a class called 'shadow' and then, via javascript, we'll swap it out for shadow-image OR shadow-css and then we're only referencing one class in the CSS.

Comment: (or...duh...I'll default to CSS shadows, and then over-ride if we need the image. I'll just reverse the logic in my original CSS)

Comment: Well, I just learned that Firebug has built in traffic monitoring. Nice! It turns out (much to my surprise, actually) that Firefox does NOT request that image. Interesting...

Comment: @DA: Isn't it because Firefox has 'myImage.jpg' in its cache? Try to refresh the page in question by pressing Ctrl-F5, thus forcing FF to skip cache checks